# What is the best framework for web application without using web/app server?

Tags: user-interface, presentation-layer

I want to deploy an web application without using web server(Tomcat,Jboss etc.) like sonar/hudson does. What presentation framework is suitable for it which has JSP/Struts like capabilites?

Comment: I want to run the web application using windows service without deploying it on the web server. Since I had a plan to use struts 2 as presentation layer but we require web server for deployment. I am looking for some MVC framework which can be deployed with an embedded server or is it possible to deploy sturts application using embedding Jetty as suggested by @Guido.

Answer (score 0):

You can use embedded [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)

> Jetty provides an HTTP server, HTTP
>   client, and javax.servlet container.
>   These components are open source and
>   available for commercial use and
>   distribution.
>
> Jetty is used in a wide variety of
>   projects and products. Jetty can be
>   embedded in devices, tools,
>   frameworks, application servers, and
>   clusters.

See this official tutorial about [embedding Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty), the Hello World is as simple as:

```
public class SimplestServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```